# NX+Nestjs typescript compiler plugin fails

Tags: webpack, importerror, nrwl-nx, nestjs-swagger

We use the https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/cli-plugin in a nrwl-nx nestjs project.

This basically works, but the build fails, when we use this import in a DTO:

```js
import {Temporal} from "@js-temporal/polyfill";
import Instant = Temporal.Instant;
```

Errormessage:

```
ERROR in ./apps/nest-app/src/app/my.dto.ts 7:148-257
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '[..]\node_modules\@js-temporal\polyfill\index' in '[..]\apps\nest-app\src\app'

webpack compiled with 1 error (2182caab897fc303)
There was an error with the build. See above.
```

Details:

- Here is a GitHub repository to reproduce the issue: https://github.com/tmtron/nx-swagger-ts-plugin-import-issue

  - When we deactivte the Nestjs typescript compiler plugin, the build is okay. So I guess the import-syntax is okay.
- When we do not use nx, but the **nest-cli directly**, everything works correctly (even with his import)

  - see this GitHub Repo: https://github.com/tmtron/nestjs-swagger-ts-plugin
  - Thus, I suppose that nx is somehow using a different webpack configuration, but I am not sure.

I'd be glad for any hints what to do next.
Maybe someone knows a workaround or has an idea where I should report an error: nestjs, nrwl-nw, webpack?